# Custom Field Type - Multiple Edit Field Settings Sections

Tags: 2010, custom-field-types

I'm currently creating a custom field type and I've followed all the online tutorials to create an edit control and I'm able to customize the "Additional Column Settings" area without any issues.

Is there a way to create additional sections for editing the field other then "Additional Column Settings"? For instance, Managed Metadata fields have:
- Additional Column Settings
- Multiple Value Field
- Display Forma
- ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's ultimately dictated by the FieldEditor user control you reference.  Here's an example for a custom SPField I recently worked on:

```
    <wssuc:InputFormSection Title="reCAPTCHA Column Settings" Description="Specify your public and private reCAPTCHA keys along with selecting a theme and default language. For more information on reCAPTCHA and to obtain your own keys go to http://www.recaptcha.com" runat="server">
        <Template_InputFormControls>
            <wssuc:InputFormControl LabelText="Public Key" runat="server">
                <Template_Control>
                    <wssawc:InputFormTextBox Title="Public Key" class="ms-input" ID="rcPublicKey" Columns="40" Runat="server" />
                </Template_Control>
            </wssuc:InputFormControl>
            <wssuc:InputFormControl LabelText="Private Key" runat="server">
                <Template_Control>
                    <wssawc:InputFormTextBox Title="Private Key" class="ms-input" ID="rcPrivateKey" Columns="40" Runat="server" />
                </Template_Control>
            </wssuc:InputFormControl>
            <wssuc:InputFormControl LabelText="Theme" runat="server">
                <Template_Control>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="rcTheme">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </Template_Control>
            </wssuc:InputFormControl>
            <wssuc:InputFormControl LabelText="Language" runat="server">
                <Template_Control>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="rcLanguage">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </Template_Control>
            </wssuc:InputFormControl>
        </Template_InputFormControls>
    </wssuc:InputFormSection>
```

If I wanted another section to show up I would just add another InputFormSection and then add whatever controls I wanted within that section.  The use of the InputForm... controls handles all the layout and formatting for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This works in WSS 3.0 but it does not seem to work in 2010 for me. Do you have an example of a 2010 implementation?

Comment: This is an example from a 2010 project I just completed.  Full source for the project can be found at http://recaptchaforsp.codeplex.com under Downloads.

Comment: This was my mistake, it works. I needed to modify my DisplayAsNewSection to return "true" in my editor control's class. Its working as expected now. Thanks